# React Select Async creatable doesn't save to the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using react select async creatable,
the data from api loads correctly and can select it also can create new values
but after selecting a choice or if not, creating a new value, seems like my titleState becomes empty, I tried consoling the state but gives me blank/empty value on console

```
const [titleState,setTitleState] = useState('')

const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
            axios.post(`sample/api`, {
                data: inputValue
            })
                .then(res => {
                    callback(res.data.map(i => ({
                        label: i.title,
                        value: i.title,
                    })))
                    console.log(res)
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const handleInputChange = (newValue) => {
        setTitleState(newValue)
    }

   const logState = () => {
      console.log(titleState) // logs empty in the devtools
   }



             <AsyncCreatableSelect
                        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                        styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
                        loadOptions={loadOptions}
                        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                        placeholder="Title Trainings"
                    />


                 <Button onClick={logState}>Click</Button>
```

then I have some button when click will console the titleState, but it doesn't log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `onChange={handleInputChange}` instead of `onInputChange={handleInputChange}`

- **onChange** triggers when a new option is selected / created.
- **onInputChange** triggers when writing a new option.

Comment: thanks man, you saved me, I thought this event was handled by the onInputChange and uses specific action for selected options.